# Django - how to write this query in a way that doesn't require DISTINCT

Tags: django, django-models, query-optimization, django-queryset

I'm working with a model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bars = models.ManyToManyField('Bar')
```

In a view I have access to a list of `Bar`objects and need to get all `Foo` objects that have any of the `Bar` objects in their list of `bars`, so I do this:

```
foos = Foo.objects.filter(bars__in=list_of_bars)
```

The issue is that there are duplicates, if a `Foo` has 2 bars, and both of those bars are in my `list_of_bars`, which a simple `distinct` solves:

```
foos = Foo.objects.distinct().filter(bars__in=list_of_bars)
```

That's all good and well, except that adding `DISTINCT` to the query makes it *very* slow, due to there being 2 million `Foo` objects in the database.

With all that said, what way(s) can you think of that don't use `DISTINCT`, but achieve the same result set? If it involves altering models, that's OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always select uniques in python:

```
foos = set(Foo.objects.filter(bars__in=list_of_bars))
```

You need query set. So, maybe (just maybe) this quick nasty hack could help You. It is ugly, but maybe it is fast (not sure about that).

```
def get_query_set(self):
    foos = set(Foo.objects.filter(bars__in=list_of_bars))
    return Foo.objects.filter(id__in=[f.id for f in foos])
```

Comment: Thanks. This is for the admin though, which requires a queryset from `get_query_set`. BTW, i think you meant to leave off the `.distinct()` in your actual query portion, no?

Comment: Fixed (``distinct()``) and added some suggestion.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because I don't think, at this point, that there is a better way, but that query (in my case) would be about 1 megabyte of SQL :)